# Redirect scikit-learn printed progress messages

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm working on a web app that uses sklearn models. Most sklearn models have an argument `verbose` that can be set to an integer ∈ `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, where a higher number will provide a higher level of verbosity. When verbose is set to an int > 0, progress messages are printed. After the messages have been printed, the final result will be returned.

How can I access those progress messages so they can be stored in a variable and transferred some place else? Since the progress messages are not returned but printed, I'm not sure if this is possible.

Code example:

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import random

# generate 10 arrays of arrays containing 9 random integers between 1 and 30
X = [[random.randint(1,30) for i in range(9)] for j in range(10)]
model = TSNE(n_components=3, verbose=3)
result = model.fit_transform(X)

# prints a bunch of progress messages and finally the result
print (result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer. I just needed to redirect print like this:

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import random
import sys
import io

# Store sys.stdout in a variable
old_stdout = sys.stdout

# Assign buffer to new_stdout
new_stdout = io.StringIO()

# Assign stdout to buffer
sys.stdout = new_stdout

# Generate 10 arrays of arrays containing 9 random integers between 1 and 30
X = [[random.randint(1,30) for i in range(9)] for j in range(10)]
model = TSNE(n_components=3, verbose=1)
result = model.fit_transform(X)

# Get values
output = new_stdout.getvalue()

# Revert to original stdout
sys.stdout = old_stdout

print(output)
```

With the help of this source: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-variable-in-python